# Reversing and displaying an input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am confused on why it is displaying the original input and the reversed input together as one. I have played around with the

`word += input[i];`

part and still cannot figure it out. Any help?

```
<script>
    var words = [];


     function displayWords() {

        $(".wordsView").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var a = $("<p>");
            a.addClass("word");
            a.attr("data-name", words[i]);
            a.text(words[i]);

            $(".wordsView").append(a);
        }
    };



    $("#typeSubmit").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var word = $("#textBox").val().trim();

        function reverseWord(input) {

        for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            word += input[i];
        }

        console.log(word);
    };


        reverseWord(word);
        words.push(word);
        displayWords(word);
    });






</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be better for reverseWord function to return the result of its calculations, the you can just run:
word = reverseWord(word);
or use a shorter version, like so:

word = word.split(‘’).reverse().join(‘’)

Answer (score 0):

`word` still contains the original word, and you're appending to it.  Use a temporary variable instead:

```
function reverseWord(input) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += input[i];
  }
  console.log(result);
  // If you want to update word:
  word = result;
}
```